# How to deploy C# MAUI app to another Windows machine when getting publich error about RuntimeIdentifiers for Android?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I have created a C# MAUI Windows application in Visual Studio Community Edition 2022 (v 17.6.5), that works perfectly on my development machine.  It also works great on other development mobile devices that I tether and test.

I would like to publish this project to another Windows machine that I own.

Based on this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder

I take these steps:

- Select Framework: net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0
  [image: Choose Framework Screenshot]
- Project --> Publish
  [image: Project Publish]
- Select distribution method: Choose Sideloading --> Next
- Select my SHA-256 current certificate --> Next Select version --> Create
- Select Packages
  [image: Select & Configure Packages]

Unfortunately, it creates this error:

```
1>------ Publish started: Project: Studio Sign-In 202307, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>Determining projects to restore...
1>All projects are up-to-date for restore.
1>Unable to determine the Android ABI from the value 'win10-x86'. Edit the project file in a text editor and set the 'RuntimeIdentifiers' MSBuild property to contain only valid identifiers for the Android platform.
========== Publish: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish started at 2:27 PM and took 02.079 seconds ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
```

Question: What can I do to get this C# MAUI appliaction to deploy to another Windows machine?  Are the steps I'm following appropriate?  Why am I getting this error?  How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**

Based on comments, I attempted to remove Android and iOS targets like this:

[image: Remove Android and iOS Targets]

When I publish, I actually get a few new options on the last publish screen.  Here they are:

[image: Solution Configuration Options]

Unfortunately, it still fails!  Here's the output:

```
1>Studio Sign-In 202307 -> E:\Documents\MAUI\Studio Sign-In 202307\Studio Sign-In 202307\bin\Debug\net7.0-maccatalyst\maccatalyst-x64\Studio Sign-In 202307.dll
1>Done building project "Studio Sign-In 202307.csproj".
1>Studio Sign-In 202307 -> E:\Documents\MAUI\Studio Sign-In 202307\Studio Sign-In 202307\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\Studio Sign-In 202307.dll
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.306\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets(221,5): error : The package ID 'Studio Sign-In 202307' contains invalid characters. Examples of valid package IDs include 'MyPackage' and 'MyPackage.Sample'.
1>Done building project "Studio Sign-In 202307.csproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 12:40 PM and took 06.325 seconds ==========
========== Package: 0 succeeded, 1 failed ===========
```

However, this time it appears the error is:  `The package ID 'Studio Sign-In 202307' contains invalid characters.`  So, I'm going to try to figure out how to change that.

Thank you!

Comment: Sounds like its trying to build for Android. UNCHECK Android target, in project properties.

Comment: Do you want to publish a .NET MAUI app for Windows with Visual Studio? You can check this document to [publish an application to a folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder).

Comment: @GuangyuBai-MSFT Thanks for the article. I just ran through the directions and still couldn't get it to work, so I'm going to update my question with this new info.

Comment: According to the picture you provide, it is the right way to publish the application to the folder. You can delete the Android target in the .csproj file and try to publish it again. If it still shows this issue, you can report it on the GitHub issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments from @Guangyu Bai - MSFT
and error messages I received, I was able to successfully create the package by doing two things:

1. Unchecking the Android Target in the project properties
   [image: Target Platforms]
2. Changing the Package ID to a valid name (no spaces or other strange characters)
   [image: New Package ID]

Here's the success screen:
[image: Success]

Console Output:

```
1>Studio Sign-In 202307 -> E:\Documents\MAUI\Studio Sign-In 202307\Studio Sign-In 202307\bin\Debug\net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0\win10-x64\Studio Sign-In 202307.dll
1>Studio Sign-In 202307 -> E:\Documents\MAUI\Studio Sign-In 202307\Studio Sign-In 202307\bin\Debug\net7.0-maccatalyst\maccatalyst-x64\Studio Sign-In 202307.dll
1>Done building project "Studio Sign-In 202307.csproj".
1>The package StudioSignIn202307.1.0.0 is missing a readme. Go to https://aka.ms/nuget/authoring-best-practices/readme to learn why package readmes are important.
1>Successfully created package 'E:\Documents\MAUI\Studio Sign-In 202307\Studio Sign-In 202307\bin\Debug\StudioSignIn202307.1.0.0.nupkg'.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Build started at 12:51 PM and took 04.337 seconds ==========
A package has been successfully built for Debug (Any CPU).
========== Package: 1 succeeded, 0 failed ===========
```